# Can you minify javascript at runtime with Microsoft Ajax minifier?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, minify

I don't have access to our build environment but do have the AjaxMin DLL in my project.  I'd like to know if I can take my bundles in my MVC-4 project and minify my javascript.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

I was hoping that after I add the bundle I can minify the file on my own in C# code vs. having a separate minified project file in source control.

Comment: By using Bundles ASP.NET will minify automatically your *.js files when you deploy in Release mode... Why do you want to minify the files manually?

Comment: @Lucian, will it also merge all the javascripts to a single file?

Comment: @Simsons yep, as long as you bundle them together in the same ... bundle :) :`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/all").Include("~/js1.js","~/js2.js"));`. This will minify and merge js1.js and js2.js into one single file at  the path `/bundles/all`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need, but in ASP.NET 4.5 bundleling and minification is done out of the box for you when you deploy your website in non-debug mode:

In the file: **~/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs**, you specify the bundles:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/all").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
```

And in your **~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml** you use the specified bundles:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- other head declarations -->

    <!-- use the css bundle -->
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- other body declarations -->

    <!-- use the javascript bundle -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/all")
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when you Publish your ASP.MVC site in the **Release** configuration the CSS and JavaScript will each be bundled and minified into their own single css and js file.

- The CSS will be dowloaded from something like: /Content/css?VoSYW5j1afpgB_oENS5Bi.
- The JavaScript will be downloaded from something like: /bundles/all?zWZPUr7GJrRS_Ux89ubfE81

The hash strings are used to prevent caching between builds.

Everything is nicely detailed [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification), it really worths to take a look.